# How do I export an entire Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I was wondering how to export an entire wordpress website. This includes all pages, the theme, any tweaks to the theme, everything... So that when I import it to another URL, it looks exactly the same in every way possible.

Comment: copy the entire directory where the wordpress files were installed, then get a copy sql dump of the database. Copy the files to the new location, and import the sql dump into the new database. When copying the files to another place you might have to edit the configuration files to tweak them to the new location.

Comment: And use [something like this](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to fix the URLs.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have no idea how to go about doing this. This is not something I excel at, clearly.

Comment: @MichaelaLeBlanc, then i would suggest using one of the many plugins made for wordpress that will do this for you like the plugin in AlexB's answer as it should do all the work for you.

Answer (score 10):

You can actually use the WordPress Duplicator plugin, check the link below:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

This plugin scans your site and creates a backup of the WordPress site then creates an installer.php file.  Download those files and put them on the new server. Run the installer.php and follow the [docs](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/quick-start/?utm_source=duplicator_free&utm_medium=wordpress_plugin&utm_content=package_built_install_help&utm_campaign=duplicator_free#quick-040-q) to be up and running in no time.

Comment: please provide more information like code example for your answer.

Comment: watch this video : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ7pHmR9JC8]
and what happens is as follows:
you get the _zip-file_ and than you can install this on your other wordpress site.

it is reccommended to read the documentation of the plugin than you can understand it.

Hope this is enough information for you.

Comment: Read this too : http://support.lifeinthegrid.com/knowledgebase.php?article=10

Comment: This plugin failed for me because it needed support for MySQLi, but the UpdraftPlus plugin worker for me.

Comment: Any idea how Duplicator compares with WP Staging plugin? Is one more thorough/better at replicating a WordPress site?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to migrate a Wordpress site.

**Plugin route (easiest)**
With plugins I'd suggest duplicator if you want something pretty standard (like a single site with a pretty standard configuration...no multi-site or BuddyPress). And if you're willing to spring a little cash BackupBuddy works well too but falls short for more complex setups.

**Manual route**
Assuming your site's url will stay the same you could just do a MySQL dump and move your PhP files from the root of your Wordpress setup. This tends to be buggy as Wordpress wasn't really designed to move in this way but with a bit of fiddling around you'll get the site back up.

I'd only choose this route if you're really comfortable with MySQL management and have at least a bit of a background programming PhP or else it could get frustrating.

**Rebuild Option**
You could just reverse engineer your site. So imagine your server went down but you had backups of your entire site: exports, themes, plugins etc. You could just re-install Wordpress then use the Wordpress importer plugin to get your data, then tweak it all to make it pretty.
A useful resource for this approach is  [Wordpress Codex article on Migrations.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

**Rsync route**
This one I haven't done myself yet but if you're extremely comfortable with your server environment and have root access you could use a tool like rsync to literally clone the server. From what I understand this is similar to how disc images work but I honestly can't tell you much more than that. I'd recommend checking out [Rsync Documentation](http://rsync.samba.org/) for more on that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to backup a Wordpress installation you just have to copy the /wp-content directory, and the database.
The wp-content directory contains the plugins, files uploaded on the site, or whatever that is specific to your site.
So later if you would like to use wp-content and the database on a new WP installation, you may have to update some modules or functions used in themes.

That said, it sometimes happens that other files in wp-admin or wp-includes are modified. It's really not a good practice but if you don't know what has been done on the WP, you better have to backup all the directories.

Comment: The FTP access is not always available and it would be great to be able to download all the files and the database using the admin dashboard of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You do as Patrick said. You have to copy your wordpress directory. If you are using a database, copy the sql dump. Once you place the directory and sql dump where you want it, you may need to change some of the code because your files will have a new location.

Just point the code in the right direction.

There is the easy way if you know how to use plug-ins. You can find many of them that will copy your Wordpress site for you to a location that you want.